# Is Dr.Crane/Scarecrow part of the League of Shadows?

Tags: analysis, the-dark-knight-rises, batman-begins

He originally works for Ra's al Ghul in Batman Begins poisoning patients with his neuro-toxin.
And in the Dark Knight Rises he is appointed judge of the court trying the rich and powerful.

Is he part of the League of Shadows or just a pawn that is used by the criminals in Gotham?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just realised in Batman Begins the following is said:

> **Bruce:** "He's not a member of the League of Shadows?"
>
> **Ra's al Ghul:** "Oh course not! He thought our plan was to hold the city to ransom."

So clearly Scarecrow was only being used as a pawn who managed to weaponize the neuro-toxin.